# Multi-file Factory method

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory-method

There are two classes **Base** and **Derived**.
**Base.h**:

```
class Base {
public:
Base* create_obj();
};
```

And **Base.cpp** :

```
#include "Base.h"
Base* Base::create_obj() {
   return new Derived();
};
```

and **Derived.h** :

```
#inlcude "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base {
};
```

If the two classes were in `main.cpp` then there would be no error. But when I put them in multiple files like above I get this error :

```
Cannot initialize return object of type 'Base *' with an rvalue of type 'Derived *'
```

Why is that? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why does `Base.h` include `Derived.h`?

Comment: I corrected it despite the fact that it was a solution to similar question and I included it so you know it is not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and do this

```
// Base.h

class Base {
public:
Base* create_obj();

};

// Base.cpp
#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived.h"

Base* Base::create_obj() {
   return new Derived();
};


// Derive.h
class Derived : public Base {
};
```

Basically I removed "Derive.h" from "Base.h" and move it to "Base.cpp". Since you don't have derived in your header there's no real need for it.

This is called a circular dependency, where you have a header file that tries to include another file, but is itself required to be included in that header file.

In your case this dependecy can be broken by just using the header in the .cpp file instead of the .h. In cases where you also need a reference to it in the header you can use forward declaration.

Comment: You'd also need to include `Base.h` in `Derived.h`. I doubt this is asker's exact code, because as written it should be complaining about `Base` not being a type before it complains about `Derived*` not being convertible to `Base*`.

Comment: Yes this solved my issue. Thanks. But I'll wait for answer to Why? question

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include Base in Derived. I corrected it. @NathanPierson

Comment: @Learner I've updated on the why. Hope this helps.